# How to revert git in to standard global config

Tags: git

I'm having issue previously with my git, last time I set the global into

```
git config --global pull.ff only
```

but now I accidentally mistype this

```
git config --global pull.ff --no-ff
```

now every time I pull I have this error,

```
fatal: Invalid value for pull.ff: --no-ff
```

I'm trying to revert it by this commands:

```
git config --global pull.ff no
// or
git config --global pull.ff only
```

but still the issue is there.

Comment: The commands you tried should work, but Git config files are easily editable as text too. What’s in your `~/.gitconfig` under `[pull]`?

Comment: Hi @Ry- just checked. ```[pull] ff = only```.

Comment: Did you maybe also forget `--global` the first time? Check `.git/config` in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope|grep pull
```

You will see all instances of pull.ff settings, and *where* they are define.

You can then remove the problematic setting.